# Vuex store.watch behavior

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm a Vuejs noob and i'm a bit stuck with Vuex store's watch function.
Here's my code for the store:

```
const storeconf: StoreOptions<any> = {
state: {
    string: 'teststring'
},
actions:{
    changeString({commit}):any{
        commit('stringChange');
    }
},
mutations:{
    stringChange(state){
        state.string=Math.random()+' root';
    }
},
modules: {
    mod:{
        namespaced:true,
        state:{
            string:'modulestring'
        },
        actions:{
            changeString({commit}):any{
                commit('stringChange');
            }
        },
        mutations:{
            stringChange(state){
                state.string=Math.random()+' module';
            }
        },
    }
}
```

..and the app:

```
new Vue({
el: '#app',
store: store,
template:'<button @click="doActions">click</button>',
mounted(){
    this.$store.watch(
            state =>[state.string, state.mod.string],
            watched => console.log(watched[0]+' -- '+watched[1]);
        );
},
methods:{
    doActions:function(){

        this.$store.dispatch('mod/changeString')
        this.$store.dispatch('changeString');

    }
}
```

The point is that when i trigger the action on the root store the watcher works perfectly, but when i trigger the namespaced module one ( mod/changeString ) the watcher does nothing at all.

What's weird to me is that the namespaced action changes properly the store value, it just won't trigger the watcher..

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you don't need watch the state. Just use comptued properties, putting the access to the state inside computed hook

Comment: I'm seeing that changes to either `state.string` or `state.mod.string` is triggering the watcher as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/vo68hpum/

Answer (score 0):

**thanksd** it does indeed.
The real project I extracted this example from is in typescript, following [this tutorial](https://codeburst.io/vuex-and-typescript-3427ba78cfa8), and it seems the problem is that module property was set as optional and not initialized. It still logged the mutation and modified the state but did not trigger any watch. Kinda weird.